# Python MySQL script does not wait on table lock

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python 3.9 against MySQL 8. In my Python script I am inserting into a small MySQL table with the following:

```
        my_db_cursor = dbi.my_conn.cursor()
        my_yr_sql = (
            'INSERT INTO cal_years '
            '(calendar_year, start_dt, end_dt) '
            'VALUES '
            '(%s, %s, %s) '
        )
        yr_info = (y, start_dt, end_dt)
        my_db_cursor.execute(my_yr_sql, yr_info)

        dbi.my_conn.commit()
        my_db_cursor.close()
        dbi.close_dbs()
```

(The variable y is an integer and the other two are datetimes.)

I know the table to be locked by a separate process. The entire set of code above executes successfully but the inserted data is not visible. When I release the locks from the other process (just do a rollback or commit there), the data inserted above is visible.

So, the insert above is waiting on the table locks to be release but it doesn't wait - it proceeds and returns success even though in the background the insert is waiting.

I was expecting the Python script to get a 'Lock wait timeout exceeded' error but instead success was returned. (All my code was inside a try block with appropriate except blocks.)

Comment: Transactions don't normally lock the entire table, they only lock the rows that were used by the queries. The whole point of row locks is to avoid blocking queries that involve unrelated rows. The data is put into a journal, and made visible when the transaction commits.

Comment: Thanks Barmar but I should have added that in addition to the INSERT above, the first thing I am doing is deleting all the rows in the table. And the select which is locking the table is a "SELECT * FROM cal_years" so the locks would conflict. I'm sure that's what is happening since as soon as I rollback or commit the other process, my inserts from the SQL above appear.